# Custom annotation processing while coding

Tags: annotations, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree, compile-time, annotation-processing

The purpose of the project I'm working on is to handle annotation at compile time, it is not focused on what exactly I'm developing.

I took a simple subject for this and I'm writing a custom collection that will store elements and provide methods to manage them.

What I wanna do is to create an annotation `@Contains`, for example, to generate `itemsContains` method that could be processed while coding (instead of writing code manually).

```
public class Array {

    private List<String> items;

    public Array() {
        items = Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "xyz");
    }

    public boolean itemsContains(String expected) {
        return items.contains(expected);
    }
}
```

Generally, I want my class to look something like:

```
public class Array {

    @Contains
    private List<String> items;

    public Array() {
        items = Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "111");
    }
}
```

The important thing I want to reach is to have `itemsContains` method show up once the annotation is applied to a field. This is how it should look like:

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnDYA.png)

Alternate existing examples are Lombok's `@Getter/@Setter`.

So what functionality or configurations should I implement to get the expected result?
Would be grateful for some real implementations or guides how to perform it step by step.

Answer (score 3):

Annotation processing does not change the source file yet it generates a new file,
`Lombok` on the other hand does a [trick](http://notatube.blogspot.com/2010/11/project-lombok-trick-explained.html) to modify the source file itself, meaning that you need to call the generated class somewhere in your code.

One way to do this is to generate a class that extends the main class

```
@Generated
public class ArrayProxy extends Array {
    public boolean itemsContains(String expected) {
        return items.contains(expected);
    }
}
```

and in your main class you need to do two things:

- first you need to make `items` protected
- you can add factory method to actually create the generated class

```
  public class Array {

   @Contains
   protected List<String> items;

   public static ArrayProxy create(){
       return new ArrayProxy();
   }

   private Array() {
       items = Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "111");
   }
}
```

And of course you need to use it like this

```
ArrayProxy array = Array.create();
array.itemsContains("expected");
```

Comment: OK, that is the solution I haven't tried. But the actual question was how can we can change the AST of the source file during the compilation like Lombok does. I understand the process of compilation and it seems that the IDE compiler is controled by Lombok or what? Some resources say that there is a custom compiler needed. Am I right ?